# Is it possible for Vim to confirm before pasting huge amount of text?

Tags: paste

I am wondering if there is a way for Vim to alarm me when I am pasting a large amount of texts (using clipboard) into it.

For example, when I am pasting more than 10000 letters, Vim can alarm me that I am pasting too much and confirm if I would like to proceed.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
nno <silent> p @=<sid>CustomPaste(v:true)<cr>
nno <silent> P @=<sid>CustomPaste(v:false)<cr>

fu s:CustomPaste(below) abort
    let register_size = strchars(getreg(v:register), v:true)
    if register_size > 10000
        let question = 'You are about to paste a long register.  Do you want to proceed? y/n'
        call popup_dialog(question, {
            \ 'filter': 'popup_filter_yesno',
            \ 'callback': function('s:ConfirmLongPaste', [a:below]),
            \ })
        return ''
    endif
    return a:below ? 'p' : 'P'
endfu

fu s:ConfirmLongPaste(below, id, result) abort
    if a:result == 1
        call feedkeys(a:below ? 'p' : 'P', 'nxt')
    endif
endfu
```

Or this:

```
vim9script

nno <expr> p <sid>CustomPaste()
nno <expr> P <sid>CustomPaste(v:false)

def CustomPaste(below = true): string
    var register_size: number = getreg(v:register)->strchars(true)
    if register_size > 10'000
        var question: string = 'You are about to paste a long register.  Do you want to proceed? y/n'
        popup_dialog(question, {
            filter: 'popup_filter_yesno',
            callback: function(ConfirmLongPaste, [below]),
            })
        return "\<ignore>"
    endif
    return below ? 'p' : 'P'
enddef

def ConfirmLongPaste(below: bool, _: any, result: number)
    if result == 1
        feedkeys(below ? 'p' : 'P', 'nxt')
    endif
enddef
```

For more info, see:

- [:h :def](https://vimhelp.org/vim9.txt.html#:def)
- [:h :map-<expr>](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#:map-%3Cexpr%3E)
- [:h :map-<silent>](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#:map-%3Csilent%3E)
- [:h :vim9](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#:vim9)
- [:h <ignore>](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3CIgnore%3E)
- [:h @=](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#@=)
- [:h feedkeys()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#feedkeys())
- [:h function()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#function())
- [:h getreg()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getreg())
- [:h popup_dialog()](https://vimhelp.org/popup.txt.html#popup_dialog())
- [:h popup_filter_yesno()](https://vimhelp.org/popup.txt.html#popup_filter_yesno())
- [:h strchars()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#strchars())

---

You need at least [8.1.1548](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.1548) for the popup functions to be available.

For older versions, try [`:h confirm()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#confirm()) instead:

```
nno <silent> p @=<sid>CustomPaste(1)<cr>
nno <silent> P @=<sid>CustomPaste(0)<cr>

fu s:CustomPaste(below) abort
    let register_size = strchars(getreg(v:register))
    if register_size > 10000
        let question = 'You are about to paste a long register.  Do you want to proceed? y/n  '
        if confirm(question, "&Yes\n&No\n&Cancel") == 1
            call feedkeys(a:below ? 'p' : 'P', 'nxt')
        endif
        return ''
    endif
    return a:below ? 'p' : 'P'
endfu
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this unfortunately did not work form me, I am using Vim 7.4, could this be the reason?

Comment: Try the code at the end.  I checked that it works on 7.4.001.

Comment: Wow, great answer!

Comment: @user938271 Sorry, I was not clear, I mean copying from clipboard using `command` + `V`, but thank you so much!